# Testcontainers: Can't get Docker image

Tags: java, spring, docker, junit, testcontainers

I'm trying to write JUnit tests using testcontainers and the problem is with starting the containers. This is my test class:

```
package com.example;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.ClassRule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.redisson.Redisson;
import org.redisson.api.RedissonClient;
import org.redisson.config.Config;
import org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

public class TestExample {

  @ClassRule
  public static GenericContainer redis = new GenericContainer("redis:3.0.6").withExposedPorts(6379);

  private RedissonClient redisson;

  @Before
  public void setup() {
    redis.start();
    final Config config = new Config();
    config.useSingleServer()
        .setAddress("redis://127.0.0.1:6379");
    this.redisson = Redisson.create(config);
  }

  @Test
  public void test() {
    redisson.getBucket("example").set("test");
    assertEquals("test", redisson.getBucket("example").get());
  }

  @After
  public void cleanup() {
    redis.stop();
  }
}
```

After running the test the following exception occurs:

```
org.testcontainers.containers.ContainerLaunchException: Container startup failed

    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.doStart(GenericContainer.java:327)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.start(GenericContainer.java:308)

Caused by: org.testcontainers.containers.ContainerFetchException: Can't get Docker image: RemoteDockerImage(imageName=redis:3.0.6, imagePullPolicy=DefaultPullPolicy())
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.getDockerImageName(GenericContainer.java:1278)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.logger(GenericContainer.java:612)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.doStart(GenericContainer.java:317)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.get(Optional.java:148)
    at org.testcontainers.utility.ResourceReaper.start(ResourceReaper.java:117)
    at org.testcontainers.DockerClientFactory.client(DockerClientFactory.java:203)
    at org.testcontainers.LazyDockerClient.getDockerClient(LazyDockerClient.java:14)
    at org.testcontainers.LazyDockerClient.listImagesCmd(LazyDockerClient.java:12)
    ... 15 more
```

I'm running this test on Fedora 31, JUnit4, Java 11, and testcontainers version 1.15.0.
Any ideas on why is the image unavailable?

Comment: Does it work, if you manually launch that docker image on your local machine (or wherever you tried running the test)?

Comment: yes, runs normally if started with docker run

Comment: Are you using Docker or another container runtime? I think it would be easier if you can share a reproducer (although on a first look, I see nothing wrong with your code):
https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java-repro